# How to find all gas stations along the route with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, search

I would like to see all gas stations for my long trip, exclusively only those, which are along the picked route.

I searched for my destination city, tap/click directions, and now I see the route. Then I tap/click search icon, then I tap/click the gas stations icon.

I have no success neither on my iOS device nor on my desktop browser, because after I search for gas stations, it shows all the gas stations what are on the current map area (including useless items, what are definitely off my route) and does not show gas stations along the route what are off the map area, even if I scroll following my route.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on an iPhone now and this works: Load your route (do not Start, just select Directions so it shows the entire route), hit the magnifying glass, and click the 'gas station' icon.

[https://www.howtogeek.com/756641/how-to-find-gas-on-your-route-with-google-maps/#:~:text=To%20get%20started%2C%20open%20Google,a%20specific%20gas%20station%20name](https://www.howtogeek.com/756641/how-to-find-gas-on-your-route-with-google-maps/#:%7E:text=To%20get%20started%2C%20open%20Google,a%20specific%20gas%20station%20name).

Comment: Thx for your answer. As described in my OP, that is exactly what I did, and it is NOT working. So we start after Directions selected, and all route is displayed in the screen. When I do what you posted as answer, (tap in the magnifying glass and tap on the gast station icon, then the map zooms into the start of the route, and displays all gas stations on the current displayed map area, even those, what have to opposite direction from the route starting point,  and when I pan along the route, the newly displayed map area does not display any gas stations...  Using latest iOS

Comment: ...btw, if you carefully examine the screenshots on the link you provided, you can see, it exactly shows what I describe as issue, and not the solution I ask for in the OP. This would be a downvote, if I had the right to downvote...

Comment: Mine shows all gas stations within the map extent along the active and alternate routes.